# Is there a way to have a wordpress post category that is functional but not visible?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I would like to display categories in posts and in post excepts, however I would alo like to use categories that help organise the display of posts around the site but are not visible.

For example a 'featured' category that may be applied to a range of posts in unconnected categories, but that are the most valuable posts to show in a particular area. I don't want the category 'featured' to show to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're looking at custom taxonomies. Custom taxonomies can be applied to multiple posts. You can control their behaviour by using arguments.

CTs looks somewhat like that and are declared in your `function.php` file

```
<?php 
/**
* Add CT to CPT
*/
add_action( 'init', 'custom_taxonomy_langues' );
function custom_taxonomy_langues() {
  $taxonomy = '_related_CPT_goes_here';
  $singular = '_CT_singular_name';
  $plural = '_CT_plural_name';
  $labels = array(
    'name' => $plural,
    'singular_name' => $singular,
  );
  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'description' => '',
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'public' => false,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => false,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => strtolower( $plural ), 'hierarchical' => 1 ),
  );
  register_taxonomy( strtolower( $plural ), strtolower( $taxonomy ), $args );
  }; ?>
```

As you can see you can control pretty every regarding the behaviour, can you query them, do they have an archive page, do you want them to show up in the admin ui, if so where ... etc

A bunch of article already exist, you can take a look at this one https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/92430/can-multiple-custom-post-types-share-a-custom-taxonomy in regards to connecting multiple CPTs to a single CT.

Comment: This does answer my question thanks - now I realise that I also no to find a way to register the custom taxonomy in the blog feed module of my WISYWIG page builder (Divi)

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom taxonomy instead.One can specify that they are not public, but still use them for querying and grouping.  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/